# Necessary and sufficient condition for stabilizer of subset to be equal to it's compliments' stabilizer under symmetric group

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G =S_n$ be a symmetric group on set $S=\{1,2 \dots n\}$. Let $T$ be a subset of $S$ and $T' = S-T$ be it's compliment. Let us define $G_T$ be stabilizer of $T$ in $G$. What is the necessarily and sufficient condition on $n$ and $T$ for $G_T = G_{T'}$?

I find that for any $n$ and $T$, $G_{T'} = G_T \implies G_T = \{()\}$ where $()$ represents the identity element of the symmetric group. I cannot find any restriction on $n$ or $T$ since $G_T$ is same in all cases. I don't know if this answer is right. Please let me know if you have any useful ideas.

Comment: Is $G_T$ the pointwise or the setwise stabilizer of $T$? Different authors use different notations for this.

Comment: @DerekHolt $G_T$ is pointwise stabilizer of $T$ and $G_{(T)}$ is setwise.

Comment: In that case, the necessary and sufficient condition on $n$ seems to be either $n=1$, or $n=2$ and $|T|=|T'|=1$. Otherwise one of $G_T$ and $G_{T'}$ would be nontrivial.

Comment: @DerekHolt how does it hold for $n=2$? could you write answer for it?

Comment: If $n=2$ and $|T|=|T'|=1$ then $G_T = G_{T'}$ because they are both trivial.